# How to count all tokens count in an collection/index

Tags: java, lucene, information-retrieval

I use Lucene 5.3.1 and I've already indexed some documents and now am trying to find a built-in function to count **all tokens count** (across the collection/index)

I know that I can iterate over all documents and make a sum on their length. But because of my complex algorithms that increases run time, I'm trying to avoid this approach. I think lucene maybe have an api for this...

After all, I googled this function (or any similar function), But I cannot find any useful link.

Now the question is: Is there any built-in function which returns **number of ALL TOKENS in collection** (i.e. whole index) ?? If not, Is there any other optimum approach?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found the solution.

I use `CollectionStatistics` in the following way:

```
CollectionStatistics collectionStats = indexSearcher.collectionStatistics("Body");
long token_count = collectionStats.sumTotalTermFreq();
```

`sumTotalTermFreq()` method returns ALL TOKENS in the collection. It's fix for any query.